# Query Jenkins for job list using a perl script

Tags: perl, jenkins

I am not sure if this question is a duplicate or not but I cannot find any example of how one would do this. Is there any way we can query jenkins for the list of jobs. I have tried using the Jenkins::API that cpan provides but $jenkins->current_status()->jobs() returns a list of hash values. I am not sure if i am supposed to somehow translate these to readable jobs in english. Any tips??

Comment: Have you tried Jenkins cli? Maybe you can use `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <JenkinsURL> list-jobs`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://metacpan.org/pod/Jenkins::API.

`$jenkins->current_status()` does indeed return hash values. Each job hash contains keys 'color','name', and 'url'. But they are nested in a list at several levels. I found `Data::Dumper` helpful in seeing the full structure.

---

**current_status**

Returns the current status of the server as returned by the API. This is a hash containing a fairly comprehensive list of what's going on.

```
$jenkins->current_status();
# {
#   'assignedLabels' => [
#     {}
#   ],
#   'description' => undef,
#   'jobs' => [
#     {
#       'color' => 'blue',
#       'name' => 'Jenkins-API',
#       'url' => 'http://jenkins:8080/job/Jenkins-API/'
#     },
# ...
#   ]
```

Example:

```
use Jenkins::API;
$jenkins = Jenkins::API->new({ base_url => 'http://localhost:8080' });

@statuses = $jenkins->current_status();

for ($i = 0;$i <= $#{$statuses[0]{'jobs'}};$i++) {
  print $statuses[0]{'jobs'}[$i]{'name'},"\n";
}
```

Comment: Im sorry if this is not obvious to me but it seems like these hash values that the jobs() method returns are keys to a hash table. What am I keying into to get the actual values (color, name, url)? Could you give me an example with code?

Comment: The example code is updated and tested, showing how to get a list of job names.